# What should be cache blocking loops and the Cache block size?

Tags: algorithm, operating-system, cpu-architecture

What should be the cache block size for cache tiling(blocking)?
or it depends on the cache size?

Suppose I am using two arrays in my code

`int array1[16000]` and `int array2[16000]`

What should be the cache blocking for this piece of code
 and add outer loops is the requirement

```
for(int i=0; i<16000; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<16000; j++)
    {
       if(array1[i]==array2[j])
       {
         ///....do something
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Definitely depends on cache size, and cache architecture.

Comment: cache blocking for the given piece of code?

Comment: If you split `array2` into parts so a part fits into the cache, then you're good. For current PCs, where L1 cache is usually 64K, you can split array2 into two parts. Or maybe, if you're lucky, you may skip splitting altogether (depending on what "do something" does).

Comment: What if i make parts of array1 and array2 using two outer loops ?

Comment: @Saddam: what would be the benefit doing it? As far as I think, it is enough to split `array2`.

Comment: I have the requiremnt to add two outer loops which works for cache blocking?

Comment: @Saddam: then please put all your requirements into the question itself. Is this a homework?

Comment: this is the only more requirement

Comment: This is not home work 
I am preparing for the exam

Comment: @geza any solution ?

Comment: @geza: Most modern x86 CPUs (Intel for a long time and AMD since Ryzen) have 32kiB L1D caches, because they're 8-way associative.  Bulldozer-family has [smaller L1D caches (which are write-through with a small write-combining cache)](https://www.realworldtech.com/bulldozer/8/).  Depending on the algo, though, blocking for L2 can be pretty reasonable, and it's usually at least 256kB private per-core.

Comment: @PeterCordes: you're right, I remembered wrongly about L1 cache size. I think that the point is here to use L1 cache as efficiently as possible, so one needs to iterate on part of array2 several times which can fit into L1 cache. So other cache levels doesn't matter too much (in real life, they can matter, of course, but in this school-exercise, I think we can ignore it)

Comment: @Saddam: I'm not familiar with these kind of exercises, so I can only give a tip. I think that you need to add two outer for loops, which are stepping coarsely, and the two inner loops stepping 1-by-1. So, basically, if you look at the 16000x16000 loop as a square, then you need to have two outer loops, which divides this square into smaller squares, and then the two inner loop visits every unit in these smaller squares.